# Comparing elements Flutter/FirebaseFirestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have a problem with getting users, whose emails are in the other user's array 'SeniorList'. It prints me empty array when i have a user with an email from

```
_seniorList
```

I'm new to a Firebase so every advice is important.

Here is Firestore DB structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJXYh.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z92tX.jpg

And Code i tried:

```
 Future<List<String>> getSeniorList() async {
  var _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  List<String> list;
DocumentSnapshot data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(_currentUser!.uid)
  .get();

list = List.from(data['SeniorList']);
return list;
}



Future<void> printSeniorNameList() async {
 final List<String> _seniorList = await getSeniorList();
 print(_seniorList);

 final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .where('email', arrayContainsAny: _seniorList)
  .get();

 final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;
 print(documents);
}
```

PS. If u can tell me how to paste Images in a right way i will be thanksfull!

Comment: the list is empty because you dont have any attribut called SeniorList in your doc

Comment: Did you tried using whereIn not arrayContainsAny? From my point of view it makes more sence

Comment: https://imgur.com/z3gurUq <= here is an Array SeniorList in doc of user which type is "Attendant". I'm wondering if i should do collections 'Attendant' and 'Senior' next to 'users' to make it clearer @Anna

Comment: whereIn changed nothing ;<    'print(_seniorList);'     prints the array values from FireStore, but when i want to print the    'result,docs'    it prints:     'I/flutter (22670): [kacper@op.pl, karol@op.pl] //here is my _seniorList
I/flutter (22670): [Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'] //here result.docs' @Dominik

Comment: Images can be added the same way as links but with exclamation mark at the beginning: `![Valid XHTML](https://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10)`. Please refer to [Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Could you please also update your answer adding a description of what exactly was changed to solved your question? It will help to make the answer more visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
Future<List<String>> getSeniorList() async {
 var _currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
 List<String> list;
 DocumentSnapshot data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('users')
  .doc(_currentUser!.uid)
  .get();

 list = List.from(data['SeniorList']);
 return list;
}

Future<bool> isSeniorAlreadyInTheList(String checkemail) async {
 final List<String> _seniorList = await getSeniorList();
 if (_seniorList.contains(checkemail)) {
  return true;
 } else {
    print('Email not in a Senior List');
    return false;
   }
}

Future<void> printSeniorNameWhoseEmailInTheList(String checkemail) async {
 bool exists = await isSeniorAlreadyInTheList(checkemail);
 Map<String, dynamic>? seniorName;
 if (exists) {
  var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('email', isEqualTo: checkemail)
    .limit(1)
    .get();
  seniorName = result.docs[0].data();
  print(seniorName!['username']);
 } else
    print('That users email is not in a SeniorList!');
  }
```

Already Works for me.